# If you are married, your house's capital gain is tax free for the first $500k. But what if your spouse is not a citizen?

Tags: united-states, real-estate, capital-gains-tax, house, house-sale

If she is not a citizen or if she doesn't not have a green card yet, does this apply?

I think the rule is that she also has to live in the house for 2 years in the past 5 years, so she will need to be on some kind of visa or status.

Comment: The answer all depends on if you can file a joint tax return.

Comment: if that is the answer, then it is an answer. I just wonder why the proper question deserve a negative vote. Maybe you didn't downvote it but somebody else did. I just feel very surprised on Stack Exchange as perfectly legitimate questions get negative votes and people say "they have the rights to downvote it." On improper questions I can understand. On proper questions I cannot.

Comment: @nopole (speculation; I haven't voted on your question) Perhaps the downvote is because you're asking about taxes but haven't added a tag to indicate which country/jurisdiction applies. Tax laws vary around the world, so such a tag is necessary to get answers that are relevant.

Comment: Each spouse can individually qualify for a $250k exemption. If you file jointly, you can say you get a $500k exemption, but that's just summing the portions you each bring to the return. If you *don't* file jointly, it's still possible that you can exempt $250k on your return, and your spouse can exempt $250k on their return.